# adding panel to select field in content type

Tags: entities, hooks, nodes

I created a content type for a new block. One of the fields in this needs to pull in category information from a magento site. I have code to get all of the categories and display them in a drop-down working in a panel template. 
The only step I am missing is know how to access this as a field in my new content type. I have read some articles about using something called hooks for this process but I'm not fully sure about how they work. 
Is a hook the best method and if so what exactly does it involve programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean ctools content types? In your edit form you need to save the value which later will be available in $conf, for a full explanation see this page for example http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/building-custom-content-panes-aka-ctools-content-types-panels-3-and-drupal-7

Comment: It's just a regular content type. I don't think ctools content types is suitable for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I would create a textfield in your content type. Then use hook_form_alter to change the textfield into a select field. I would use a textfield instead of list(text) because your allowed values will change depending on the response from the other site. Check out https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 you need to change the form elements #type and add #options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments I used the hook_form_alter but instead of pulling in the panel I just created another function to get the information and used that as the options for my select.

```
  function gacms_magecp_content_type_edit_form($form, &$form_state) {

   $conf = $form_state['conf'];
   $categories = gacms_magecp_categories();

    $form['magecp'] = array(
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#options' => $categories,
     '#title' => t('Mage Category Product'),
     '#default_value' => isset($conf['magecp'])?$conf['magecp']:'',
     '#format' => isset($conf['format'])?$conf['format']:'full_html',
    );

    return $form;
  }

   function gacms_magecp_categories(){
    db_set_active('magento');

    $result = db_query("SELECT entity_id, name FROM catalog_category_flat_store_1");
        while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
           $content[$row['entity_id']]= $row['name'];
        }
        db_set_active();
        return $content;
    }
```